# getting screenshots from google street view

Tags: image, google-maps, google-street-view

I'd like to embed Google Street View on my website and according to my plan I want users to make giftcards from Street View screenshots. Users won't take screenshots with Print Screen so I'd like to provide pictures for them straight from Street View.

There's an example of a screenshot with actual coordinates in the [Google Maps API documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/#introduction).

How can I get theses pics from Street View and how does coordinates' change system work?

Which numbers should I use and how as coordinates for needed screenshot?

How can I get URL of the pic the user is watching right now?

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be legal to sell their imagery. The image itself is a fairly simple URL which you can get from inspecting the source of the page; or even from the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/#url_parameters). Which doesn't answer the question: I'll knock something up.